# Find and remove specific items from numeric array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

```
$list = array('red', 'blue', 'white', 'green', 'black', 'orange', 'brown', 'violet', 'magenta');
```

Before doing var_dump($list), how can I remove item having key [3] and item with the value "orange", and then var_dump($list) without those items?

(Have to use "if" statement - school assignment)

Comment: unset() and array_search(); ok using **if** then a  foreach() loop and == and unset() will be fine

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($list as $key => &$value)
{
    if ($value == 'orange' || $key == 3)
    {
        unset($list[$key])
    }

    echo $value . "\n";
}
```

What have you tried though? working through problems will help you become a better programmer.

Comment: you give him the exact answer, *then* ask what he has tried !?

Answer (score 0):

Without loop

```
    $list = array('red', 'blue', 'white', 'green', 'black', 'orange', 'brown', 'violet', 'magenta'); 
    unset($list[3]);
    unset($list[array_search('orange', $list)]);
    var_dump($list);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be solved using the foreach above, or you could use the criteria that you only need to use an "if" statement.

Combining the two answers above would give a more efficient solution:

```
unset($list[3]);
if (($key = array_search('orange', $list)) !== false)
    unset($list[$key]);
print_r($list);
```

unset simply eliminates that element from the array.  I will get the $key for 'orange', if it exists, then unset it, and finally print the array.